# Python script is running. I have a method name as a string. How do I call this method?

Tags: python

everyone. Please see example below. I'd like to supply a string to 'schedule_action' method which specifies, what Bot-class method should be called. In the example below I've represented it as 'bot.action()' but I have no idea how to do it correctly. Please help

```
class Bot:
    def work(self): pass
    def fight(self): pass

class Scheduler:
    def schedule_action(self,action):
       bot = Bot()
       bot.action()

scheduler = Scheduler()
scheduler.schedule_action('fight')
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [getattr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
class Bot:
    def fight(self):
       print "fighting is fun!"

class Scheduler:       
    def schedule_action(self,action):
       bot = Bot()
       getattr(bot,action)()

scheduler = Scheduler()
scheduler.schedule_action('fight')
```

Note that getattr also takes an optional argument that allows you to return a default value in case the requested action doesn't exist.

Answer (score 7):

In short,

```
getattr(bot, action)()
```

getattr will look up an attribute on the object by name -- attributes can be data or member methods The extra `()` at the end calls the method.

You could get the method in a separate step, like this, as well:

```
method_to_call = getattr(bot, action)
method_to_call()
```

And you can pass arguments to the method in the usual way:

```
getattr(bot, action)(argument1, argument2)
```

or

```
method_to_call = getattr(bot, action)
method_to_call(argument1, argument2)
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if it applies in your situation, but you may consider using a function pointer instead of manipulating the strings.

```
class Bot:
    def work(self): 
        print 'working'
    def fight(self): 
        print 'fightin'

class Scheduler:
    def schedule_action(self,action):
       bot = Bot()
       action(bot)

scheduler = Scheduler()
scheduler.schedule_action(Bot.fight)
scheduler.schedule_action(Bot.work)
```

Which prints:

```
fightin
working
```

If you can do this, it will give you an error about a misspelled function <strike>at compile-time</strike> when the code is interpreted instead of during run-time.  This could shorten your debug cycle for stupid data-entry errors, especially if the actions are done over a span of time.  Nothing sucks more than running something overnight and discovering that you had a syntax error in the morning.

Comment: Strongly consider this option. If you want to dynamically choose a method to call, this could be the right option  for you. Only use the `getattr`-based options if you're generating the name in some convoluted fashion (such as reading it from a file, from a socket, or from user input).

Comment: True that it will give an error earlier in the situation you described, but the error is not at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Scheduler:
    def schedule_action(self,action):
       bot = Bot()
       boundmethod = getattr(bot, action)
       boundmethod()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def schedule_action(self,action):
         bot = Bot()
         bot.__getattribute__(action)()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a dictionary to map methods to actions. For instance:

```
ACTIONS = {"fight": Bot.fight,
           "walk": Bot.walk,}

class Scheduler:
    def schedule_action(self, action):
        return ACTIONS[action](Bot())
```